# How to submit a form clicking on a checkbox?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with checkboxes.

And I need to submit the form clicking on a checkbox.

Could you clarify me, how can I do it ?

Is it possible to do it using Drupal Form API only, without Ajax Framework or Javascript/JQuery ?

Comment: This is not possible without javascript ..

Comment: you could use css to hide the checkbox and put a submit button next to it and style it like a checkbox. then, on click it will submit the form, set the value for the checkbox and process the form values as usual. but JS would be preferable solution.

Comment: Is it not bad practice / bad UX to submit a form by checking off a checkbox instead of a button? Anyway... you'd need to attach Javascript to submit the button with something like `$('form#id').submit();`

Comment: Could you clarify me, can I get the triggering element if i do submit the form via JS/JQuery ? And will the submit callback execute in this case ?